# How can I remove brown coloring/stains from logs?

Tags: wood

The outer walls in a log cabin are solid logs.  I had a slight leakage problem through fittings between some of them which left brown stains on the logs.  The leakage problem is long gone but the stains remain.  Any idea how I can remove them?  If I paint over them would the stains eventually seep through?

[image: coloring on logs]

Comment: Is there a tag for the special problems that those of us with log homes have?

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem with building a 10" round log home, some of the logs got wet. We tried everything including sandblasting to remove it.

The only solution we found was 40 grit sandpaper on a random orbital sander to really rough it up and remove 1/16" to 1/32" of wood before we switched to 120 and 200 grit to smooth it back out. Matching the stain might be tough though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Thompsons wood stripper/stain remover.You may have to do the whole wall or put a dark stain on all it to get it to all match.

Answer (score -2):

Take a clean paintbrush, some water and get the wall wet again. The sooner you do that, the easier it will be to get rid of these stains.

Comment: Please explain how this will help to remove the stains. Thanks!